# Swift extend navigationBar height and add segmentControl

Tags: ios, swift

I've designed following UINavigationBar however i'm a bit confused whether it is possible to add a segmentControl like this below? What would be the best way to achieve such?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension of UInavigation bar.  (Sorry, doesn't answer Peter's question.)

In Xcode, File - New - Swift File- Name the class.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


extension UINavigationController
{
    func makeBlackNavigationbar (){

        print("black navigation")

        navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    }
}

extension UINavigationBar
{

func makeBlackNavigationBar ()
    {
        barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
        titleTextAttributes = titleDict as [NSObject : AnyObject]
    }
}
```

It can be implemented anywhere in the project.

```
self.navigationController?.makeBlackNavigationbar()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.makeBlackNavigationBar()
```

Comment: This is for Swift 4       func makeBlackNavigationBar ()
    {barTintColor = UIColor.black
        let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.marine]
        titleTextAttributes = titleDict as [NSObject : AnyObject] as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]}

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic your requirement as follows:

```
-(void) segmentAction: (UISegmentedControl *) segmentedControl
{
    // Update the label with the segment number
    NSString *segmentNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0d", 
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex + 1];
    [(UITextView *)self.view setText:segmentNumber];
}              
- (void) loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    // Create a central text view
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] 
        initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:96.0f];
    textView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    self.view = textView;

    // Create the segmented control
    NSArray *buttonNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        @"Recent", @"Popular", @"My", nil];
    UISegmentedControl* segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] 
        initWithItems:buttonNames];
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    segmentedControl.momentary = YES;
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    // Add it to the navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
}
```

or there is another approach as follows:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[NSString stringWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Recent", @"")],
[NSString stringWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Popular", @"")],
[NSString stringWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"My", @"")],
nil]];

segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];


[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSegment:) 
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[segmentedControl setFrame:[self.navigationController.toolbar bounds]];

[self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:segmentedControl];
```