# Swift: Add segmented controller to a navigation bar, and keep the title + nav buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I'd like to add a segmented controller to a navigation bar, below the title.

At the moment, I've got a storyboard UITableViewController with a CoreData-sourced dynamic table, embedded in a UINavigationController.  I'd like the UISegmentedController to differentiate the sorting of the table.

There seems to be obj-C solutions available [stackoverflow.com/questions/29480433/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480433/swift-extend-navigationbar-height-and-add-segmentcontrol?lq=1)  and [stackoverflow.com/questions/18813563](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813563/add-segmented-control-to-navigation-bar-and-keep-title-with-buttons), but I'm looking for a Swift solution, that resembles the native apps.  I've also tried putting the segmented controller into a table cell with little success (can't get the action recognised).  I'd prefer not to abandon the table view controller.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you tried to convert the obj-c code to swift?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the UITableViewController with a UIViewController and UITableView, then added the UISegmentedController to a UIToolBar positioned below the UINavigationBar.

I used removeShadow for the navbar, then clipsToBounds for the toolbar.  I also added another View to simulate the bottom shadow on the toolbar (because I couldn't get the toolbar shadow/background position function to work).